# IN clause in oracle guaranteed order

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have SQL that:

```
select name, city, age 
from Student where (name, city) 
in (('Tom1','CiTy1'),('Tom2','CiTy2'),...,('TomN','CiTyN'))
```

The result of SQL guaranteed order?

Ex:

```
Name ----- City  ----- Age
Tom1   |   CiTy1   |   10
Tom2   |   CiTy1   |   17
Tom3   |   CiTy1   |   15
..............
TomN   |   CiTyN   |   09
```

Comment: IN clause will not guarantee the order of output. You have an ORDER BY clause for that.

Comment: The only way to get a guaranteed sort order is to use `ORDER BY`. Or are you asking on how to sort the result in the same order as the values in the `IN` list?

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply use the following ordering, because the text numbers won't sort properly (most likely):

```
ORDER BY city, name
```

But we can remove the text components, cast to int, and then sort:

```
SELECT
    name, city, age
FROM Student
WHERE (name, city) In (('Tom1','CiTy1'), ('Tom2','CiTy2'),...,('TomN','CiTyN'))
ORDER BY
    CAST(REPLACE(city, 'CiTy') AS INT),
    CAST(REPLACE(name, 'Tom') AS INT)
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you'd need to add an order by clause in order to guarantee the ordering.

If you want your in clause to determine the order, you could do something like:

```
select name, city, age 
from Student where (name, city) 
in (('Tom1','CiTy1'),('Tom2','CiTy2'),...,('TomN','CiTyN'))
order by case when (name, city) in (('Tom1', 'CiTy1')) then 1
              when (name, city) in (('Tom2', 'CiTy2')) then 2
              ...
              when (name, city) in (('TomN', 'CiTyN')) then 99999999;
```

Comment: Thank for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The **only** way to get a sorted result is to use `ORDER BY`.

You can use a regular expression to remove any non-numeric character, convert that string to a number and then sort by that number:

```
select name, city, age
from student
where ..
order by to_number(regexp_replace(name, '[^0-9]', '')), 
         to_number(regexp_replace(city, '[^0-9]', ''))
```